# fix aspect ration of size of SurfaceView to fix as 4:3 in Android when screenOrientation chages

Tags: android, surfaceview

In my android application,`SurfaceView` is size of  (320*240, 4:3) in when `screenOrientation` is landscape mode.
When i rotate mob to portrait mode, SurfaceVeiw gets size of (240,340),how can i force `SurfaceView` to maintain aspect ration of 4:3 when `screenOrientation` gets changed. 
I m using `Absolute`/`Frame` Layout.

How can i fix aspect ration of size of `SurfaceView` to fix as 4:3 in Android.? 
Thanks and Regards,

Comment: One example: https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/AspectFrameLayout.java